Can we move data then start an upgraded Cassandra 4.1 in RHEL 8?
I am planning to upgrade my 6 node Apache Cassandra from 3.0 (RHEL 7.9) to 4.1 version (RHEL 8) without downtime. We are moving to new RHEL 8 server. We are upgrading with 4.1 version on the new RHEL 8 server. Please help us how can I do it without a downtime.

Can we move the data prior to the upgrade window and just start the cassandra 4.1 in RHEL 8 during the window?
What is the best way to copy the data? Export/Import or SSTableloader

Please advise.

It is best to seperate the two major upgrades to isolate and easily tackle issues, if there is any.
For your question 1, the answer is a straight no.
For upgrading Cassandra® version, it is best if you plan and execute through established procedures such as this one if you want to achieve this with zero hits in your environment in case of an in-place upgrades.
It is also best if you prepare by going over the set of changes and understand which is applicable to your own setup/deployment from the below guides for the versions that is of interest to you,

changelog
other news and upgrade guideances

If you don't prefer using the in-place upgrade procedure above and hop multiple major versions prior to your desired target version, you could achive this other open-source tools such as the Zero Downtime Migration (ZDM) that is available for you. Go through the procedure and good luck with your upgrade of both C* version as well as the operating system!

It is possible to just "swap out" the nodes with an upgraded server (has RHEL 8 + Cassandra 4.1 installed) as if you were replacing the underlying hardware with the replace_address_first_boot flag.
With the "replace" method (1) there is no downtime involved, (2) there are no topology changes so you don't need to do any decommission/bootstrap, and (3) the node is back online within just a few minutes.
NOTE - The new servers do NOT need to have the same IP addresses as the existing nodes. Cassandra will be able to handle the new IPs.
The procedure is a variation of replacing a dead node. Here are the high-level steps to implement it:
Preparation
STEP P1 - Install Cassandra 4.1 on the new RHEL 8 servers.
STEP P2 - Configure Cassandra on the new servers to be the same as existing nodes including the same cluster_name and seeds list.
WARNING - Do NOT copy the cassandra.yaml from the existing nodes to the new servers. You need to use version 4.1 of the cassandra.yaml since the old 3.0 configuration will not be compatible with the new servers.
Replacement
STEP 1 - Starting with a seed node, force memtables to be flushed to disk so there won't be commitlogs to be replayed on startup with:
$ nodetool drain

STEP 2 - Shutdown Cassandra on the node.
STEP 3 - Unmount the data volume on the node.
STEP 4 - Modify conf/cassandra.yaml and set the cluster name to REPLACED so that the node will not accidentally re-join the cluster if it gets restarted:
cluster_name: 'REPLACED'

STEP 5 - Mount the data volume on the new RHEL 8 server. Make sure that the directories are configured with the new paths in cassandra.yaml.
STEP 6 - Start Cassandra 4.1 on the new server and monitor the startup by "tailing" the logs, for example:
$ tail -f /var/log/cassandra/system.log

Cassandra is operational on the node when it starts listening for CQL clients on port 9042 (the default).
STEP 7 - Repeat steps 1 to 6 on the next seed node until all seeds have been replaced.
STEP 8 - Repeat steps 1 to 6 on the next remaining node until all nodes have been replaced.
NOTE - If the data disk is not on a volume that can be unmounted, you can modify the procedure by manually copying the whole data/ directory (and all its subdirectories as-is) from one node to the corresponding new server.
Other items
WARNING - There are several operations which are NOT possible while the cluster is running with mixed Cassandra versions:

Do NOT make any schema changes in the middle of this procedure or it will result in a schema disagreement.
Temporarily suspend repairs -- all operations which involve streaming will not work.
Do NOT perform any topology changes (decommission/bootstrap) -- all operations which involve streaming will not work.

WARNING - SSTables (data files) will be in Cassandra 3.0 format so you will need to schedule SSTable upgrades at some point. They don't need to take place immediately since C* 4.1 will be able to read the old format so it is fine to delay them until after hours when there is low traffic to the cluster.
As a final note, you should test and practice this procedure in a test environment at least once (preferably twice) until you are confident that you have a good understanding of the procedure. Cheers!
